# Does Windows BitLocker reduce system performance

Tags: performance, bitlocker, tpm

I found that my computer has a TPM module to work with BitLocker but now I'm trying to see if it may reduce my system performance...

There's my spec:

```
Intel Core 2 Duo 3.0Ghz (VT-x)
2GB of DDR2-800 RAM (upgrading to 4GB soon)
160GB Western Digital 7200RPM
```

I want the best performance 'cause I'm a .NET and Web developper...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe it would with a Core 2 Duo, although I have not tested it myself (I have never used BitLocker, even though I have TPM chips in some of my harware), but it does not (so much?) with the latest Intel and AMD chips, which have [**support for hardware AES encoding/decoding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set).

Comment: If it would with a Core 2, then it should with the latest AMD/ Intel chips. It wouldn't be noticable really, but it'd still be there.

Comment: @ekaj: I do not understand what youare talking about, but the AES instruction set makes a lot of difference.  https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=intel+core+aes+instructions&hl=en&rls=com.microsoft:en-gb:IE-Address&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=rrWDT5zkA8rt8QOI99C_Bw&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CBEQ_AUoAQ&biw=1085&bih=985

Answer (score -1):

Normally yes. Just upgrade the RAM to 1333 and you are almost done. 4 GB as you will rarely find 2 GB 800.

The slowness is not very noticeable. As you see, it's the same as you compare Windows 7 basic to Windows 7 Ultimate. The slowness is noticeable on low hardware but rarely makes a difference on new hardware PCs. Did that make sense?